# ld: "undefined reference to symbol 'sqrtf'" error with G++ via Apache Ant

Tags: ubuntu, ant, g++, cmath

Recently, I'm trying to use Apache Ant with g++4.8 with `-std=c++11`.

If I tried this code it passed.

```
#include <cmath>
...
sqrtf((float)100);
```

However, if I type:

```
#include <cmath>
...
sqrt((float)100);
```

The g++ compiler will produce the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: undefined reference to symbol 'sqrtf@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Adding `-lm` doesn't help either. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not apache ant, in some Linux distributions the g++ and gcc compilers require "-lm" to link the cmath lib that is included by "math.h" in C and "cmath" in C++

Comment: Nope, not exactly in this case cause I'm able to use the command by terminal ``g++ test.cpp -o test.o`` without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It seems that Apache Ant is a bit different from the command line using g++ which needs to add the `-lm` function with a linking argument as follows.

```
<linkerarg location="end" value="-lm">
```

Since I'm not familiar with Ant, the first time I wrote the argument with no location and Apache Ant gave me an error. :(